# Prevent mouseenter/mouseleave events while dragging jquery ui slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a page that contains a few jQuery UI sliders. The page also contains a few div elements with `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` handlers for displaying tooltips. Dragging text or images over the divs does not trigger the tooltips, as expected. However, moving the mouse over the div elements while dragging a slider handle does trigger the tooltips.

jsFiddle showcasing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/JCKYs/4/

Is it possible to prevent all `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` events while dragging a jQuery UI slider?

One solution I came up with is to create a global flag that signals whether a slider is being dragged. The flag is updated in the `start`/`stop` handler of all the slider objects on the page. I can then check the state of this flag in all the `mouseenter` handlers to prevent the tooltip from being displayed.

Is there a more general solution that doesn't involve updating all my event handler code? Since this behavior already exists for text/image dragging, I thought there might be a better solution out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easily accomplished by adding a floating div behind the mouse when sliding begins.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JCKYs/5/

Change `var debug = true;` on the first line to `var debug = false;` to make it transparent.